# Symfony locale is not available in the layout

Tags: symfony, twig, locale

I am trying to set a *locale* in Symfony and everything works fine except the places where I try to translate or generate route in the layout file. 
I created a listener so I can set the locale on every request.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {

private $container;
private $defaultLocale;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, $defaultLocale = 'en') {
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
}

public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
        return;
    }
    // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter

    $loc = $this->defaultLocale;
    if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
        //$request->getSession()->set('lang', $locale);
        $event->getRequest()->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        $event->getRequest()->setLocale($locale);
        $loc = $locale;
    } else {
        // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
        $request->setLocale($this->defaultLocale);
        $event->getRequest()->getSession()->set('_locale', $this->defaultLocale);
        $loc = $this->defaultLocale;
    }

    $this->container->get('translator')->setLoc($loc);
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return array(
        // must be registered after the default Locale listener
        KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 15)),
    );
}
```

}

If in the twig template I try to access the session variable with **app.session.get('_locale')** that stores the locale it is as it should be - I get the desired result. But when I try **app.request.locale** I get the default locale not the one that is in the url. And because of that all my routes are prefixed with the default locale and everything is translated with the default language. How can I get the locale from the url in my layout and generate routes and translations with it?

Comment: Did you clean the cache?

Comment: Have you properly defined your routes to "expect" a locale as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, I did both of this. My templates have the proper locale but the layout that they extend doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use only one way to handle the locale translation.

I implemented this action

```
/**
     * @Route("/{_locale}")
     */

$request->setLocale('en');
$request->getSession()->set('_locale','fr');
$localesArray = [
            'request' => $request->getLocale(),
            'request_default' => $request->getDefaultLocale(),
            'config_default' => $this->getParameter('kernel.default_locale'),
            'session_locale' => $request->getSession()->get('_locale'),
            'request_attributes' => $request->attributes->get('_locale')
        ];



        var_dump($localesArray);
        die();
```

An the answer is this one

```
array(5) { 
["request"]=> string(2) "en" 
["request_default"]=> string(2) "nl" 
["config_default"]=> string(2) "nl" 
["session_locale"]=> string(2) "fr" 
["request_attributes"]=> string(2) "es" 
}
```

As you can see when I changed the locale by setLocale did not affect the other results. I get the result accessi this url "/es" and my default locale for this test was "nl". Compare results

My advice: work only with request locale as describe this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html#content_wrapper)